# Comment solved the problem and someone else copied the comment to answer. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600699/constrained-linear-least-squares-for-xa-b-in-matlab), my problem was solved in the comment (let's say, by user A). However, three hours later, someone else (user B) slightly rephrased the comment to answer my question, with no new contribution. Then, another person (user C) spotted this and added "As 'user A' commented, " at the beginning of B's answer.

Now, I'm not really sure about what to do with B's answer. Should I

- Accept this answer since this is a correct answer?
- Flag this answer?

Comment: See [Ripping off answers from comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210663/ripping-off-answers-from-comments) and [What to do with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a) on the Overmeta.

Comment: I see. Reading through the links you gave me, I learned about community wiki and found that the answer was made as a community wiki. Seems like it is a totally valid answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [Ripping off answers from comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210663/ripping-off-answers-from-comments) and [What to do with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a) on the Overmeta, It is okay to steal comments that answer the question and post them as an answer. If you are not comfortable with stealing rep, you can mark it as a community wiki.